# Alignment of the bond

Tags: chemfig

I'm trying to draw the Lewis structure of hydrocloric acid, including the partial charge and dipole moment. Unfortunately, the bond is not aligned "in the middle". Is there a way to "move" the bond?

### Here is the code I've used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \chemname{
    \chemfig{\Charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:,135:3pt=$\delta^-$}{Cl}(-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{a})
    -[,1.5]
    \Charge{45:5pt=$\delta^+$}{H}(-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{b})} 
    \chemmove{\draw[____|->, very thick] (b)--(a);}}{hydrocloric acid}
\end{document}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thanks!
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Please, can you put the complete code with all the package, `\documentclass` etc?

Comment: Of course, sorry!

Comment: Deleting `\usepackage{classicthesis}` and `\usepackage{arsclassica}`, that it is not very important for a minimal working example, your code have a problem to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

The `\charge` macro places the `<charges>` out of the bounding box while `\Charge` places them into the bounding box. (manual p.32)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemname{
\chemfig{
    \charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:,135:3pt=$\delta^-$}{Cl}
            (-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{a})-[,1.5]
    \charge{45:5pt=$\delta^+$}{H}
            (-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{b})
    }
    \chemmove{\draw[____|->, very thick] (b)--(a);}
}{hydrocloric acid}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can the charge (negative) be on the right hand side of the chlorine ion(superscript)